# Proper versions of cryptography and paramiko to run together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, sftp, paramiko

I suddenly started getting cryptography/paramiko errors the other day when I upgraded my Python's runtime version from 3.7 to 3.7.10. The exact error I'm getting is: `type object 'EllipticCurvePublicKey' has no attribute 'from_encoded_point'`

I'm also running `cryptography=2.4` and `paramiko=2.4.2`. I tried upgrading `cryptography` to 2.4.2 as well and 2.5 but still keep getting the same errors.

Paramiko is a dependency for another another package that I'm using, `pysftp` so I don't explicitly use `paramiko`.

Any help in getting the two packages to work together would be much appreciated.